# Replace all column values with value from single column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to replace values in all columns within a `df` using integers from a specified column. Using the `df` below I want to use the values in `Code` and replace them in all other columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Place' : ['X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y'],                                
    'Number' : ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H','I'],          
    'Code' : [1,2,3,0,1,2,5,4],    
    'Value' : ['','','','','','','','']                  
    })

df[:] = df['Code'].apply(lambda x: x if np.isreal(x) else 0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Intended Output:

```
  Place Number  Code Value
0  1     1      1    1     
1  2     2      2    2     
2  3     3      3    3     
3  0     0      0    0     
4  1     1      1    1     
5  2     2      2    2     
6  5     5      5    5     
7  4     4      4    4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reindex`, `ffill`, `bfill`

```
df[['Code']].reindex(columns=df.columns).ffill(1).bfill(1).astype(int)

Out[256]:
   Place  Number  Code  Value
0      1       1     1      1
1      2       2     2      2
2      3       3     3      3
3      0       0     0      0
4      1       1     1      1
5      2       2     2      2
6      5       5     5      5
7      4       4     4      4
```

---

Numpy solution

```
df[:] =  np.transpose([df.Code] * df.shape[1])

Out[314]:
   Place  Number  Code  Value
0      1       1     1      1
1      2       2     2      2
2      3       3     3      3
3      0       0     0      0
4      1       1     1      1
5      2       2     2      2
6      5       5     5      5
7      4       4     4      4
```

Comment: @jonboy: you are welcome. Glad I could help. To make it complete, I edited the answer to add numpy solution for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    df[df.columns] = df[['Code', 'Code', 'Code', 'Code']]
```

or:

```
    df[df.columns] = df[['Code']*len(df.columns)]
```

Hope it helps you.